# How do I get my link_to to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I have created a basic forum, however I'm stuck trying to get the "posts" to be linkable underneath the categories.

How it's set up: I have a category which is the first level of CRUD, then I have a second CRUD within the category. What I'm struggling with is linking to the category/id/post/id.

The code I use in the view is:

```
#posts
    - @category.posts.each do |post|
        .post
            %h4.title= link_to post.title, post
            %p.date
                Published
                = time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
                ago by:
                = post.user.email
                Replies: 
                = post.comments.count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
link_to post.title, [@category, post]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it was so simple -.-

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using nested resources, you need to pass `category_id` into your link URL. You can do it like this:

```
link_to post.title, [@category, post]
```

Comment: Ok how about this?

I have a form which is part of a "comments" object, which is the child of a "post" object which in turn is the child of a "Category" object,

I get the above error message with the following code (using simple_forms)

Any advice?

    = simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
 = f.input :comment, label: "Your Reply", input_html: {class: "form-control"}
 = f.submit

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one

```
<%= link_to post.title, category_post_path(post.category_id, post) %>
```

I hope this will work